# NVD3.js multiChart x-axis labels is aligned to multiple lines, but not multiple bars

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

This question relates to [NVD3.js multiChart x-axis labels is aligned to lines, but not bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626557/nvd3-js-multichart-x-axis-labels-is-aligned-to-lines-but-not-bars)

I am using NVD3.js `multiChart` to show **multiple lines** and **multiple bars** in the chart. All is working fine, but the x-axis labels is aligned only to the line points, not bars. I want to correctly align labels **directly below the bars** as it should. But I get this:

[image: x-axis labels is not aligned to bars]

As you can see - x-axis (example, 2014-Feb) is not aligned to **Bars**.

1) How to align x-axis labels to **bars and lines at the same time**?

2) I need this solution for `NVD3.js` or how to properly integrate.

I made jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n2hfN/28/

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem here is that `nv.models.multiChart` uses a linear scale for its x-axis, and then when it draws the bars it calls `nv.models.multiBar`, which uses an ordinal scale with `.rangeBands()`.

You can follow this mess through the source code:

First lets look at `multiChart.js`

[HERE](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/6616c9e9314a73ed7d23a76eda8e82ecc697630b/src/models/multiChart.js#L27) is where it sets the x-scale to be a linear scale.

[HERE](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/6616c9e9314a73ed7d23a76eda8e82ecc697630b/src/models/multiChart.js#L34-L35) it calls the `nv.models.multiBar` model to create the bars.

If we jump over to have a look at `multiBar.js`

[HERE](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/6616c9e9314a73ed7d23a76eda8e82ecc697630b/src/models/multiBar.js#L11) it creates an ordinal scale, and [HERE](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/6616c9e9314a73ed7d23a76eda8e82ecc697630b/src/models/multiBar.js#L109) it sets the range of the scale using `.rangeBands()`

The result is that the ordinal scale used for placing the bars, and the linear scale used for the chart's axis do not align. Here's what the two scales look like on their own if plotted on an axis:

[image: d3 ordinal vs linear scale]

The solution would be to force the chart to render the line graphs and the x-axis in terms of the ordinal scale used by the bars. This would work in your case because the bars and the lines all use the same data for the x-axis. This is very simple to do if you are making your own chart and not relying on nvd3, as I showed in my answer to your previous question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626557/nvd3-js-multichart-x-axis-labels-is-aligned-to-lines-but-not-bars). This is extraordinarily complicated to do if you're trying to work within nvd3, and many others have tried and failed to switch out the default scales used by nvd3 charts. Have a look at [this issue on the nvd3 github page](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/issues/29) that has been open since January, 2013 for example.

I've tried a number of approaches myself to reuse the bars' ordinal scale, but with little success. If you want to poke around and try to brute-force it yourself, I can tell you that from my experiments I came closest when using `chart.bars1.xScale().copy()` to make a copy of the bars' scale, and set its domain and rangeBands. Unfortunately, since the chart's width is computed at render time, and I can't seem to create a hook into the `chart.update` function, it is impossible to set the rangeBands' extent to the correct values.

In short, if you can't live with the labels being offset, you're probably going to need to code up your own chart without nvd3, or else find a different type of layout for your visualization.

Answer (score 5):

After playing around with the NVD3 v1.7.1 source code with the *immensely* helpful guidance offered by jshanley's answer, I think I've managed to come up with an answer (perhaps more of a kludge than a good solution).

1. What I did was to have the x-axis labels align with the bars, and have the line data points align with the bars.

   1.1. To align the x-axis label, I shifted the x-axis to the right so that the first label appears underneath the middle of the first bar. I then shifted the last label to the left, so that it appears underneath the middle of the last bar. See code [here](https://github.com/mlawry/nvd3/blob/b78f3348a20120528f0163b30d4564d32de1c816/src/models/multiChart.js#L278). The amount to shift by is computed at drawing time using `.rangeBand()` and saved in a `rbcOffset` variable (I had to modify `multiBar.js` for this to work).

   1.2. To align the line data points with the bars, a similar shift is also required. Luckily, this part is easy because `scatter.js` (which is used by line chart) comes with a `padData` boolean variable that does what we want already. So basically, I just set `padData` to true and the lines shift to align with the bars, see [here](https://github.com/mlawry/nvd3/blob/b78f3348a20120528f0163b30d4564d32de1c816/src/models/multiChart.js#L263).
2. In order to properly integrate with NVD3 and make everything look good, some additional changes are required. I've forked NVD3 on GitHub so you can see the complete solution there. Of course, contributions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I use last solution and it runs. So, you can specify

`lines1.padData(true)`

in order to align lines too.

Comment: Can you please provide jsFiddle (you can modify one of the existing)?

Comment: This only aligns the line chart with the bar chart but the xAxis labels are still not aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, I used the last solution,it worked for me as well. Find the following line in multiChart.js

```
if(dataLines1.length){
    lines1.scatter.padData(true); // add this code to make the line in sync with the bar
    d3.transition(lines1Wrap).call(lines1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! i will check it.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and fixed it with below code:

at lines 7832 and 7878 replace

```
.attr('transform', function(d,i) { return 'translate(' + x(getX(d,i)) + ',0)'; })
```

with :

```
var w = (x.rangeBand() / (stacked && !data[j].nonStackable ? 1 : data.length));
var sectionWidth = availableWidth/(bars.enter()[0].length - 1);
if(bars.enter().length == 2)
    return 'translate(' + ((i-1)*w + i*w + (i*(sectionWidth - 2*w))) + ',0)';
else
    return 'translate(' + ((i-0.5)*w + i*(sectionWidth - w)) + ',0)';
```

The first case handles multiple bars case while the second one handles single bar case.

Answer (score 0):

lawry's solution works. Also if using interactive guidelines, you need to shift the interactive line to match the new scale. Modify:

```
if(useInteractiveGuideline){
                interactiveLayer
                    .width(availableWidth)
                    .height(availableHeight)
                    .margin({left:margin.left, top:margin.top})
                    .svgContainer(container)
                    .xScale(x);
                wrap.select(".nv-interactive").call(interactiveLayer);    
                                                                          
                //ADD THIS LINE 
                wrap.select(".nv-interactiveGuideLine")
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + rbcOffset +', ' + 0  + ')' +
                'scale(' + ((availableWidth - rbcOffset*2)/availableWidth) + ', 1)');
            }
```

in multiChart.js.