# nvd3.js multiChart layout headache

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I try to establish a mutiCart with d3 and nv.d3 js.All is ok but I am caught by a layout problem which I spent tons of time to research but in vain.

As you can see here the x axis value is not properly positioned, which should be positioned under the center of each bars.I would like to know if it is possible to have this issue fixed or not.And there is a relevant post here:
[NVD3.js multiChart x-axis labels is aligned to multiple lines, but not multiple bars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797605/nvd3-js-multichart-x-axis-labels-is-aligned-to-multiple-lines-but-not-multiple)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVl3d.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK3Qa.png)

Here is my codes to call API

```
<script>
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 30, left: 40};
var data={
    //mianData,axisKeys,svg
   mianData:[
   {"key":"Failed",
      "type":"line",
      "color": 'yellow',
      "yAxis":1,
      "values":[{"x":0,"y":4},{"x":1,"y":7},{"x":2,"y":1},{"x":3,"y":4}]
   },
   {"key":"Client Impacting",
    "type":"line",
    "color": 'red',
    "yAxis":1,
    "values":[{"x":0,"y":0},{"x":1,"y":3},{"x":2,"y":0},{"x":3,"y":1}]
   },
   {
       "key" : "emergency",
       "type":"bar",
       "color": 'yellow',
       "yAxis":2,
       "values": [{"x":0,"y":8},{"x":1,"y":14},{"x":2,"y":17},{"x":3,"y":12}]
    },
    {
       "key" : "normal",
       "type":"bar",
       "color": 'blue',
       "yAxis":2,
       "values": [{"x":0,"y":452},{"x":1,"y":708},{"x":2,"y":699},    {"x":3,"y":612}]
    },
    {
       "key" : "routine",
       "type":"bar",
        "color": 'lightblue',
       "yAxis":2,
       "values": [{"x":0,"y":538},{"x":1,"y":412},{"x":2,"y":349},{"x":3,"y":338}]
     },
     {
       "key" : "total",
       "type":"bar",
       "color": 'green',
       "yAxis":2,
       "values": [{"x":0,"y":998},{"x":1,"y":1134},{"x":2,"y":1065},{"x":3,"y":962}] 
    }
   ],
   axisKeys:["Sep-14","Sep-21","Sep-28","Oct-5"],
   svg:"#chart svg"
}enter code here


draw(data);

function draw(o){
  nv.addGraph(function() {
         var chart = nv.models.multiChart()
        .options({reduceXTicks:false })


        .margin(margin)
        .color(d3.scale.category10().range());

        //chart.x(function(d,i){ return i;});



        chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function(d){
            // If there is such element, return it
            if(typeof o.axisKeys[d] !== "undefined"){
                return o.axisKeys[d];
            }
            return "";

        }) .showMaxMin(false);
    // Get normalised data for chart
    var seriesData =o.mianData;
    // Get max values for each axis
    var minY1 = 0;
    var minY2 = 0;
    var maxY1 = 0;
    var maxY2 = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < seriesData.length; i++) {
        var _axis = seriesData[i].yAxis;
        var _values = seriesData[i].values;

        // Walk values and set largest to variables
        for(var j = 0; j < _values.length; j++) {
            // For maxY1
            if(_axis == 1) {
                if(_values[j].y > maxY1) {
                    maxY1 = _values[j].y;
                }
            }
            // For maxY2
            if(_axis == 2) {
                if(_values[j].y > maxY2) {
                    maxY2 = _values[j].y;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Set min, max values of axis
    chart.yDomain1([minY1, maxY1]);   //0,7
    chart.yDomain2([minY2, maxY2]);  //0,1134
    // Set chart
    d3.select(o.svg)
        .datum(seriesData)
        .call(chart);

    // Auto resize chart on window resize
    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);
    return chart;
  });
 }
</script>
```

Comment: This problem is fixed by using the codes in  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797605/nvd3-js-multichart-x-axis-labels-is-aligned-to-multiple-lines-but-not-multiple floor 2.